# How to integrate with BlackBerry Java SDK with BlackBerry WebWorks in one application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I want to develop some modules with BlackBerry Java SDK in my application, and develop other modules with BlackBerry WebWorks. That I could take the advantage of both Java SDK & WebWorks. I don't know how to integrate them in one application.

Comment: as you know, we develope a screen in html & js for WebWorks, and develop a screen with java for Java SDK. I want to know how to switch  between these two type screens.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider choosing one or the other. All the major APIs are accessible via WebWorks, and if you need a Java component you can [build an extension](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_developing/Creating_and_using_a_JS_extensiong_in_your_widget_1316872_11.html).

The other way around, I suppose you could use some kind of webview that uses local html/css/js assets alongside a Java app, but that's a mess. You're better off just going with WebWorks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebWorks to create your UI and then, what ever Java code you have you would have to import the Extension (.jar file) to your WebWorks project.

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_developing/using_javascript_extensions_1866976_11.html